# Is there a CLI (Command Line Interface) for GoLang?

Tags: debugging, go, command-line-interface

Totally new golang user here and I don't see a CLI tool but just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking it. It appears everything just compiles down to a binary that you can run, even when debugging?

Comment: there is no REPL

Comment: A CLI tool for what?

Comment: Any time you run a Go application, it results in a native binary. Debugging, "go run file.go", unit testing, they all produce binaries.

Answer (score 2):

Go does not have a CLI that must be used when invoking a application written in Go. There is a go command that is "... a suite of programs to build and process Go source code". You can find more information about this in the [command documentation](https://golang.org/doc/cmd)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, you can check it out here
https://thenewstack.io/cli-command-line-programming-with-go/

Comment: That doc is on how to *write* a CLI tool in Go.